# React rendering issue for Ad display

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ads

I am thiking of Ad network such as Google Adsense, Outbrain etc.
I want to insert the ad within the contents but the ad is also refresh again and again every time react render the view. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Did you try to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

React offers a variety of ways to manage and assist its decision making when it comes to updating components.

Use a key for the component containing the ad. React will be able to more intelligently know if a component needs to update or not. This could alleviate some or all of the pain in the refresh on your client.

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Another possibility, is to provide some logic for when the component should update (and change the ad) or not with the `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle method

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate